# Intel XDK change info.plist

Tags: ios, cordova, ssl, ios9, intel-xdk

I have an app developed on Intel XDK (the worst decision I ever made) and when I test this app on iOS 9 I get the error: "Failed to load resource: An SSL error has occurred and a secure connection to the server cannot be made."

At first I implemented SSL certification on my server. No luck on resolving this error.

Searching a little bit, I discovered that it's possible to make this error go away by adding some information to the info.plist file.
I need to add this to the info.plist file:

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
            <true/>
            <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
            <dict>
                <key>yourdomain.com</key>
                <dict>
                    <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
                    <true/>
                    <key>NSThirdPartyExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
                    <false/>
                </dict>
           </dict>
    </dict>
```

But I can't find a way to change my info.plist on Intel XDK.

How can I add these information to my info.plist file on Intel XDK? Is it even possible to do that? Why isn't Intel fixing it???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically I feel there are two approach to resolve this issue:

One way is to skip this iOS security using [iOS security plugin](https://github.com/robertklein/cordova-ios-security)

Second option is to use [custom config plugin](https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-custom-config) which allows you to manipulate and set values of your choice in -*.plist file using values configuration in config.xml

Please note that this is tested approach by me using Cordova CLI. You should be able to pull it off in Intel xdk too I guess.

Comment: I added the iOS security plugin and still no luck... I wonder if the problem is Intel XDK or cordova

Comment: @FredericoNovackAmaralPereir This is something to do with Intel XDK as its working fine with cordova CLI

Comment: I will try to move this project from Intel XDK to another technology. Why even adding HTTPS to my calls I still get this error?

Comment: @Frederico you need SSL certificate signed by third party CA to make it work in iOS. Self signed certificates won't work in iOS.I feel you are already facing issues with Intel XDK, so better keep it simple. Even vannila HTML,JavaScript, CSS should be fine for Cordova app in most cases. Good luck. Keep us posted and plz do accept the answer once you feel its helpful. Cheers

Comment: I aceepted this as answer. But not because it solved the problem (yet) but for others to see how bad intel xdk is. I'm going to start learning React Native, witch looks a way better alternative. I'll keep posting any solutions I will find.

Comment: @Ganghi running my app with cordova CLI still gives me the same problem!

Comment: @Frederico could you elaborate the issue? Are you trying http or HTTPS? Is the security skip plugin installed? Is your .plist file updated?

Comment: The info.plist file is perfectly updated. All my requests are being made with HTTPS. I tried to make the info.plist to allow all calls and also tried to specify the domains. No luck.

Comment: @Frederico As I mentioned earlier, for HTTPS to work you need certificate issued by third party CA. Self signed certificate won't work

Comment: @Frederico also your post question is focused about updating the .plist file which you are able achieve now. So wondering why the answer was unaccepted?

Comment: Sorry, you're right. The question was answered, but not my problem. I'll try a little bit more to fix my app. Although I'm thinking about making this project native for iOS because I can't fix this problem.

Comment: @FredericoNovackAmaralPereir Thats not a wise decision to make it native. I guess with further more insight you should be able to crack it with proper certificate

Comment: When you say the SSL certificate must be issued by a third party CA what exactly do you mean? Because I used Go Daddy system to issue my certificate. This is the web site: https://www.cardapioalfenas.com.br

Comment: @Frederico All I meant is that it should not be a self signed certificate. I guess you already have valid certificate issued by third party.Also ensure that you dont have any certificate errors while trying to access your web application in browser